# jquery ui autocomplete match

Tags: jquery-ui

I implemented jquery autocomplete ui on my page..
But when i search for example "am" every word which CONTAINS "am" is going to be listed in the drop down.

But i want just the words which BEGIN with "am" should be listed.

I dont know how to do that.. can you help me plz?

Comment: I got it from a Servlet and datatype is jsonp

Comment: So why not do the filtering on your servlet? The autocomplete just displays what your datasource supplies (mostly)

Comment: Lol thats a really good question ;-) Didnt even think about it... thanx. Problem solved :P

Comment: Posting it as an answer so people don't need to go through the comments for the solution. You can accept it if that solved your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're getting the data from a serverside datasource, you should filter the data that is being returned to the autcomple control. The control will just show whatever data that is returned to it.