# jQuery UI Autocomplete match by first set of letters?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, filter

Say this is my autocompletion array:

```
Pascal
PHP
Lua
JavaScript
ActionScript
Active Server Pages
```

When I type in 'a' now into the autocomplete textbox, it will show Pascal, Lua, JavaScript, ActionScript and ASP. That is because they all have the letter 'a' in them. But I only want to display ActionScript and ASP, as they have 'a' as the first letter. How is this possible?

I've seen this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646170/jquery-ui-autocomplete-match), but it seems to be not useful, as I have the data on the page (Pascal, PHP, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is based on the way you filter the values from the list. For e.g., if the source is a SQL Server table or view then the filter condition has

```
WHERE Col = '%' + ValueInAutoCompleteTextBox + '%'
```

and hence you get Pascal, Lua, JavaScript, etc. In which case, you can just remove the earlier '%' to achieve what you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote it as answered, if it really help you in solving your issue.

Comment: sorry, that day it said I had to wait like 15 minutes, so I left. I apologise.

Comment: No at all. Am glad that I was able to help you, resolve your issue.